# Direct button to UIViewcontroller with different classes

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a CollectionView with over 10 different buttons. Is there a way that I can change the view controller depending on the button pressed? Let me know your ideas! I'll be on to respond to any confusion if there is any.

Comment: Im not sure I fully understand. Are the buttons in the collection view cells? And depending on which button is pressed, it goes to different views?

Comment: Yes, the buttons are cells. And yes, depending on which button is pressed it goes to a different view. I'll change the questions to clarify.

Comment: Have you considered instead of using buttons in the cells, using the didSelectItemAtIndexPath method? Or does the cell contain other things that prevents this?

Comment: No, there is nothing in the cell besides the button. How would I use the didSelectItemAtIndecPath?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the didSelectItemAtIndexPath method to check which item was pressed and go to different views depending on the row.

In this method:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

you can call your changes here by checking the indexPath.row

```
switch indexPath.row {
    case 0 : 
        //do changes for first button
    case 1 :
        //do changes for second button
    ...
    case 9 :
        //do changes for tenth button
    default : 
        print("Error : button press wasn't handled")
}
```

Comment: Oh, I see. I'll try it out.

Comment: Let me know if you run into any issues